# Angular Reactive form how to prevent triggering duplicate changes

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have a simple reactive form with one input field.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const updateOnObj = { updateOn: 'change' };
    this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      onechar: [ null, Validators.minLength(1) ],
    }, updateOnObj);    
    this.mainForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => { 
     console.log(`Value changed ${value}.`);
    });
}

<input id="char"class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="onechar" tabindex="1" 
placeholder="Type a char">
```

When I type a character eg. 'A' the change detection triggering a value change which is ok.
But, when I again type a char 'A' instead of what I previously typed, so I select the typed char 'A' and replaced it with a new 'A' char, it also triggering a change.
How can I prevent it, when typed again the same char?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) operator:

```
this.mainForm.valueChanges.pipe(distinct())subscribe((value: string) => { 
     console.log(`Value changed ${value}.`);
    });
```

Comment: @Laszlo, did it work for you?